# heroku and rails, background image gets complied but not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

The background image is visible in local host and I checked and saw that the image got complied when pushed up to heroku, however it is not visible on the deployed site. The path of the image is app/assets/images/

This is how i called the image in my application.css
[image: This is how i called the image in my application.css]

Answer (score 0):

you should use: add the background img in your view, but the best practice is with scss. With Scss you'll get helpers like `asset-url('whiteLogo.png')` for this job. For your case, you can just add to your html tag:

```
<html style="backgound: url('<%= image_path 'whiteLogo.png' %>')"></html>
```

But it's a BAD PRACTICE.

Have a nice day.